# Bash script string quotation error

Tags: bash

I am running mariadb in a docker container and I am try to back it up via cron and a bash script. I can't figure out the correct syntax of the ' and "

This is what I want to do, this works when I insert it into my terminal:

```
docker exec mariadb sh -c 'exec mysqldump --single-transaction -u myDb_user -p"secret" myDb' > tmp.sql
```

This is the line of code which causes the error in my bash script (should do the exact same thing than the line above, but in a bash script and with a few variables (need to back up multiple things):

```
#!/bin/bash
...
docker exec mariadb sh -c 'exec mysqldump --single-transaction -u ${dbUser} -p"${dbPassword}" ${database}' > "${backupdir}/${fileNameBackupDb}"
```

The output when I run the bash script (via sudo ./backup.sh)

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for the feedback @dessert

Comment: Are those variables defined inside the container? You have used single quotes, your script isn't going to expand them

Comment: Updated my question, please have a look, thanks! @muru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the correct syntax:

```
docker exec mariadb sh -c "exec mysqldump --single-transaction -u ${dbUser} -p'"${dbPassword}"' ${database}" > "${backupdir}/${fileNameBackupDb}"
```